# find the source of duplicate data in an Ember.js view

Tags: node.js, ember.js, redis, socket.io

A while ago I made a chatting app using Socket.io, Redis and Node.js. Recently, a friend forked my repository on Github and implemented the same chat implementation in Ember.js. I figured I'd help along, because a lot of the stuff he added broke a lot of the functionality of my code. I've tried fixing it as much as I can, where I can. The two problems I want to fix though, are duplicate pieces of data.

I'm no Ember.js expert - I barely know the framework. There are two issues I'd like to fix: In the user's online list - there are duplicate usernames. When submitting a message, two messages with the same content appear.

I've had a look at Redis locally while trying to find the bug and nothing is duplicate in Redis. The code in app.js doesn't have any errors that are obvious enough for me to spot either.

Here's a link to the repositories for code reference as they are much too large to add here (live examples are in the README's):

https://github.com/declandewet/ember-js-chatapp/ (my fork of his repo)
https://github.com/declandewet/chatapp (my repo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the current_users.push into the part that cycles through and adds it to redis seemed to fix it.